# R object's name carrying through multiple functions

Tags: r, nse, r-s3

In line with my reading of [Hadley's advice on building S3 objects](https://github.com/hadley/adv-r/blob/master/S3.Rmd#classes) I am using a helper function, a constructor function, and a validator function. A simple reproducible example:

```
test_object <- function(x, y, z) {
    new_test_object(x, y, z)
}

new_test_object <- function(x, y, z) {
    structure(list(x = x,
                   y = y,
                   z = z,
                   x_name = deparse(substitute(x))),
              class = "test_object")
}

validate_test_object <- function(test_object) {
    # Anything goes
    test_object
}
```

I would like the resulting object to include a value with the original name that the item passed in had (`$x_name` in the above example). The `deparse(substitute(...))` trick works if I call the constructor directly:

```
alpha = "a"
test_constructor <- new_test_object(x = alpha, y = "b", z = "c")
test_constructor$x_name
# [1] "alpha"
```

But not if I use the helper function:

```
test_helper <- test_object(x = alpha, y = "b", z = "c")
test_helper$x_name
# [1] "x"
```

I would like `test_helper$x_name` to also return `[1] "alpha"`.

Short of doing the `deparse(substitute(...))` step at the helper stage, is there any way of the constructor function (`new_test_object()`) accessing the 'original' name of the object `x` if it has come via the helper? Or to ensure that its name passes through with it as the helper function passes it to the constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's really the purpose here? If you are just using one function as a wrapper to another, then there are better ways of preserving arguments. For example

```
test_object <- function(x, y, z) {
  call <- match.call()
  call[[1]]  <- quote(new_test_object)
  eval(call)
}
```

But in general relying on `deparse()` to get information from names of variables isn't a very reliable method. It would be better to have such pieces of information be proper parameters that you can set if you like. This makes your functions much more flexible.

```
test_object <- function(x, y, z, xname=deparse(substitute(x))) {
    new_test_object(x, y, z, xname=xname)
}

new_test_object <- function(x, y, z, xname=deparse(substitute(x))) {
    structure(list(x = x,
                   y = y,
                   z = z,
                   x_name = xname),
              class = "test_object")
}
```

Comment: Honest answer to "what's really the purpose here?": because Hadley said so! His logic is that the helper "provides a convenient and neatly parameterised way for others to construct and validate (create) objects of this class.". I like your suggestion or properly parameterising it - seems neat and like it will do the trick well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a not beautifull fix: you add `...` argument to pass the name when you are calling it from another function

```
test_object <- function(x, y, z) {
  x_name = deparse(substitute(x))
  new_test_object(x, y, z, x_name = x_name)
}

new_test_object <- function(x, y, z, ...) {
  args <- list(...)
  if(is.null(args[["x_name"]])){
    structure(list(x = x,
                   y = y,
                   z = z,
                   x_name = deparse(substitute(x))),
              class = "test_object")
  }
  else{
    structure(list(x = x,
                   y = y,
                   z = z,
                   x_name = args[["x_name"]]),
              class = "test_object")
  }

}
```

And here is the result:

```
test_helper <- test_object(x = alpha, y = "b", z = "c")
test_helper$x_name
# [1] "alpha"
```